# Did Huygens understand light to be a transverse wave or a longitudinal wave?

Tags: optics, waves, visible-light, history, huygens-principle

We have [this](https://scienceready.com.au/pages/particle-and-wave-model-of-light#:%7E:text=Huygens%27%20model%20of%20light%20assumes,the%20motion%20of%20water%20surfaces.) source that claims Huygens "assumed light to be longitudinal", which contradicts [this](https://byjus.com/physics/wave-theory-of-light/#:%7E:text=Huygens%20believed%20that%20light%20was%20made%20up%20of%20waves%20vibrating%20up%20and%20down%20perpendicular%20to%20the%20direction%20of%20the%20wave%20propagation) source which claims "Huygens believed that light was made up of waves vibrating up and down perpendicular to the direction of the wave propagation".

I must admit, neither source is entirely accurate or reliable, so what exactly was Huygens formulation regarding the nature of light?

Comment: I don't think it really matters, I might be wrong, but I cannot think of any circumstance of his principle that relies on an assumption about the nature of the wave (long. vs trans)

Comment: "Fresnel.. advanced a theory of light in which waves exhibit transverse vibrations." [Saleh, Fundamentals of Photonics].  Fresnel was born 93 years after Huygen's time.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of links, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about history not physics

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited for HSM StackExchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly interesting quote
from the "Note by the translator" section (page ix)  of
"Treatise On Light" by Huygens, Christiaan
https://archive.org/details/treatiseonlight031310mbp/page/n10/mode/1up

(bolding mine)

> The Treatise on Light of Huygens has, however, withstood the test of time: and
> even now the exquisite skill with which he applied
> his conception of the propagation
> of waves of light to unravel
> the intricacies of the phenomena of the double refraction
> of crystals, and of the refraction of the atmosphere,
> will excite the admiration of the student of Optics.
> It is true that his wave theory was far from the complete
> doctrine as subsequently developed by Thomas Young and Augustin
> Fresnel, and belonged rather to geometrical
> than to physical Optics. **If Huygens had no conception
> of transverse vibrations**, of the principle of interference, or of the existence
> of the ordered sequence
> of waves in trains, he nevertheless
> attained to a remarkably
> clear understanding
> of the principles of wave-propagation;
> and his exposition of the subject marks an epoch
> in the treatment of Optical problems.